# ruby, undefined method `text' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby

Sometimes the price of the items in the result is not defined, so whe I run this code :

```
price =  result.search('span.result-price')[0].text
```

I got :  undefined method `text' for nil:NilClass

Is there anyway how to avoid this exception and assign for example price = $0000 when it's not defined.
Thanks.

Comment: `...[0]&.text || '$0000'`

Comment: Ruby has no String#text or Array#text methods, so this isn't vanilla Ruby. Why would you think this particular array element would `respond_to? :text`, especially if your search method returns `nil`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have several options

```
price_element = result.search('span.result-price')[0]
price = price_element ? price_element.text : '$0000'
```

or

```
price = (result.search('span.result-price')[0].text rescue '$0000')
```

from Ruby 2.3.0 you can take advantage of safe navigation operator

```
price = result.search('span.result-price')[0]&.text || '$0000'
```

Comment: never use the second variant with `rescue '$0000'`.

Comment: I think it's the perfect use case. In this case, it does not hide something else. Or, better, for whatever reason you can't find the price text, use that default. It's very effective in this case.

Comment: But I know in Ruby exceptions are avoided. It does not make much sense. Whatever.

Comment: Let's imagine you have a typo: `resultt.seraarch('span.result-price')[0].tex rescue '$0000'`. Already not a perfect use case, right?

Comment: No, please, don't use *Pokemon exception handling*. You are capturing *all* exceptions and presuming everything's fine, when it might not be. Use conditional navigation. Only `rescue` like that when you're absolutely certain that every exception, no matter the origin, is not a big deal. That's rarely the case, and it's absolutely not the case here. This sort of "or whatever" handling paves over serious issues, like what @Ilya is talking about. Hiding bugs like that could subtly break something and it may take months to find out.

Comment: @tadman I understand what you're saying. But I'm imagining a case where for whatever reason you can't find the price text, that default should be used. @ llya if you never test the happy path we have totally another problem.

Comment: There's a huge difference between "can't find" and "code crashed out for unexpected reasons". Not being able to find is `&.text`. Other reasons cause exceptions and those should be visible. This is the difference between "If there's nothing left in the coffee pot, add water" and "No matter what happens, add water." which is going to be bad when there's an electrical fire.

Comment: It's just an instance. Ok,let's imagine that `result.search` is a call to the external resource and connection is bad (`Timeout::Error`). How often you test such cases? How will you investigate this issue with clean logs?

Comment: Yes Ilya but I think the whole program isn't limited to this line. I think this line alone is pretty safe. Anyway, I understand you all reason and I suggest to the user to not use the second option too.

Comment: As Ursus points out, there are lots of ways to avoid calling `nil#text`, but the OP hasn't provided enough context. It might make for better code to fix #search, or to rely on data structures other than Array. This is a case where asking the OP for clarification is probably The Right Thing™ to do, rather than posting a quick-and-dirty answer that may not really help future visitors.

Answer (score 2):

The reason you get this error is that `price =  result.search('span.result-price')` returns an empty array.

You then try to address array element with index 0 which doesn't exist and hence returns `nil`.

To avoid the exception you can use the following:

```
price =  result.search('span.result-price')[0].try(:text)
```

In case `result.search('span.result-price')[0]` exists it will return the text and if it doesn't it will return `nil`