# Error fetching status: undefined method `text' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby

I Don't know anything about Ruby, found code below which reports AWS status

https://gist.github.com/ktheory/1604786

```
  /1.rb https://status.aws.amazon.com/rss/a4b-us-east-1.rss
    Error fetching status: undefined method `text' for nil:NilClass
```

ruby -v
ruby 2.5.1p57 (2018-03-29 revision 63029) [x86_64-linux]

```
latest_status = xml_doc.css("item title").first.text
print lastest_status
in `<main>': undefined method `text' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ruby, undefined method \`text' for nil:NilClass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51991597/ruby-undefined-method-text-for-nilnilclass) Asked 3 hours ago with nearly the same exact title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `first` comes up empty and returns `nil` you can't just blunder along or your code will crash. You need to tread carefully:

```
latest_status = xml_doc.css("item title").first&.text
```

Or, if you're using an older version of Ruby and have ActiveSupport from Rails:

```
latest_status = xml_doc.css("item title").first.try(:text)
```

Or else you're going to need to do it the hard way:

```
latest_status = xml_doc.css("item title").first
latest_status &&= latest_status.text
```

You should probably figure out why that selector isn't working as it might not be correct and ends up returning nothing.